# Union of all the rational curves in a complex algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Can the union of all the rational curves in a complex algebraic variety contain a complex ball and not be the whole variety?

Comment: Hi, I think that you should provide more context and your own thoughts on this problem.

Comment: If your variety is not irreducible then yes. For example take the curve $x(x^3+y^3+z^3)=0$ in $\mathbb P^2$. Otherwise no (but I don't know a reference). The idea is that for any rational curve the rational curves in the same homology class sweep a closed subvariety. And there will be a countable number of such subvarieties. They can not cover a ball unless one of them has top dimension, i.e. coincides with the whole variety

Comment: @aglearner Yes the variety is required to be irreducible. What if instead of rational curves we ask about irreducible curves of arithmetic genus at most 2?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  For every projective algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field, for every integer $g$, the union of all irreducible curves in the variety of geometric genus $\leq g$ is a countable union of closed subvarieties of the variety.  In particular, if the countable union contains an open subset (for the Zariski topology, or for the Hausdorff topology when the field is $\mathbb{C}$), then the union of the curves equals the entire projective variety.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you! But if we consider irreducible possibly singular curves of arithmetic genus $\leq 2$ is it still true?

Comment: @lacon.  With further thought, no that is not true.  Begin with a product variety $\mathbb{P}^1\times C$ where $C$ is a smooth, projective curve of genus $>2$.  Now choose $n>2$ points on one of the rational curves $\mathbb{P}^1\times \{t\}$ and let $X$ be the non-normal variety obtained by identifying the $n$ points in $\mathbb{P}^1\times C$.  The union of all irreducible curves of arithmetic genus $\leq 2$ equals the image of $\mathbb{P}^1\times (C\setminus \{t\})$.

Answer (score 2):

I am just posting my comments as an answer.  The OP clarified that they want to use the "arithmetic genus" and not the "geometric genus" when working with irreducible singular curves in a projective variety.  With this clarification, the question has a negative answer (both the original question for genus $0$ and the question for genus $\leq 2$): the union of all irreducible curves in a projective variety having arithmetic genus $0$, respectively having arithmetic genus $\leq 2$, is typically not a union of countably many closed subvarieties.  Thus, even if the union contains a nonempty open subset, it can happen that the union is not the entire projective variety.

One negative example arises from the non-normal variety whose normalization equals $\mathbb{P}^1\times C$, where $C$ is a curve of genus $>2$ and where the normalization morphism is an isomorphism away from a length-$n$, finite subset of a fiber $\mathbb{P}^1\times \{t\}$, where $n>2$.  The curves of geometric genus $\leq 2$ in the non-normal variety are images of curves of geometric genus $\leq 2$ in the normalization, and these are each of the form $\mathbb{P}^1\times \{s\}$, for a choice of closed point $s$ of $C$.  The image of such a curve in the non-normal variety has arithmetic genus $0$ if $s\neq t$, but has arithmetic genus $>2$ if $s$ equals $t$.  Thus, the union of the irreducible curves of arithmetic genus $\leq 2$ equals the image in the non-normal variety of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times (C\setminus \{t\})$.

If one uses "geometric genus" instead of "arithmetic genus", the answer is positive.  The union of all irreducible curves in a projective variety having geometric genus $\leq g$ is a countable union of closed subvarieties of the projective variety.  Thus, if this union contains a Zariski dense subset (over an arbitrary field) or contains a nonempty open subset for the Hausdorff topology (over $\mathbb{C}$), then the union equals the entire projective variety.