# Union of all the entire curves in a complex manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a connected closed complex manifold. Let $S$ be the set of non-constant holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to X$.

If $\bigcup\limits_{f\in S}f(\mathbb{C})$ is a proper subset of $X$ can it have non-empty interior?

Comment: The earlier question https://mathoverflow.net/q/392234/210298 was about the algebraic case

Comment: You probably want more conditions on $X$ to make it interesting, maybe compactness?  For example, let $X\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ be the open, connected subset consisting of pairs $(x,y)$ with $|y|<3$ and $|y|<1$ when $|x|<1$. By Liouville's Theorem, the only non-constant holomorphic $f:\mathbb{C}\to X$ are $f(z) = \bigl(h(z),c\bigr)$ where $|c|<1$ and $h$ is entire and non-constant.  These fill out the domain $Y\subset X$ with $|y|<1$, which contains a complex ball, but no nonconstant $f$ passes through the point $(2,2)\in X$.

Comment: @RobertBryant that's right

Comment: You probably mean to ask whether it contains an *open* ball.

Comment: @Kapil No I think a closed ball would work too.

Comment: @lacon: sure, but not a closed ball of radius 0, and an open ball is what guarantees that.